# Use data structure references more commonly

Tags: perl, reference

I have been reading some of the perl513*delta files and I have seen some of the new features coming to Perl 5.14. Beginning with Perl 5.13.7 many of the array/hash functions will work [on array/hash refs as well](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/blog/756). While this probably is seen mostly as syntactic sugar, or Perl doing what you expect, I wonder, will/should this change the paradigm of declaring data structures in Perl? With the known caveat that it breaks compatibility with eariler Perl's, what would be the arguements for and against using anonymous structures primarily?

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use 5.13.7;

my $hashref = {
  english => 'hello',
  spanish => 'hola',
  french => 'bon jour'
};

foreach my $greeting (keys $hashref) {
  say $hashref->{$greeting}; #use say since we need a later version anyway
}
```

rather than the more traditional way using a named hash (`%hash`).

P.S. If this is seen are augmentative I can change to CW, but I am curious to hear some perspectives.

Comment: This would have the added benefit that you wouldn't have to use tied variables as often. You could just use classes with overloading.

Comment: Interesting.  Yes, using this feature will prevent your code running on older Perl versions.  Because of the huge installed base of older Perl versions, I would avoid it unless you know you'll have control over what Perl versions you'll be running.  (It's just syntactic sugar after all.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ability to use certain array and hash functions on references is just syntactic sugar and need not impact the way you work with first level plural structures.  There are several reasons for this:

given `my $array = [1 .. 10]`

- List processing functions like `map`, `grep`, `sort`, `reverse`, `print`, `say`, `printf` and many others still need to be passed proper lists, so this means using `@$array` vs the simpler `@array` with these functions.
- The `for/foreach` loop needs to be passed a list, requiring `@$array`
- `$array` is always true, to determine the length you need to write `@$array`

  ```
  while ($array)  { infinite loop }
  while (@$array) { what you probably wanted }
  while (@array)  { no room for error here }
  ```
- sub-scripting a real `@array` as `$array[$idx]` is marginally faster (~15%) than `$array->[$idx]` since a dereference does not need to happen on each access.  The difference with hashes is smaller, around 3%, due to the overhead of the hashing function.

Basically, by moving to all references, you get a different set of functionality that needs to use the dereferencing sigils.  Instead, take advantage of pre `v5.13.7` functionality for anything you are declaring for immediate use `my @array; my %hash;` and utilize the new syntax shortcuts in areas where you would have used excessive `@{ ... }` or `%{ ... }` constructs with the applicable functions.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, speed comparison etc. Plus I had forgotten about scalar context on an array to get its size. I had noticed the for/foreach while preparing my example. Well thanks, I was just overthinking things as usual.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this upcoming change will break backward compatibility. Now you get an error on `keys $hashref`, with perl 5.14 it will be working. So effectively no current code could be using such feature.

Comment: not backward compatibly in that sense. I meant that if I write code the way I mentioned, it would not work on older versions. You would need `use 5.14` (is that the right syntax?)

Comment: `use 5.14.0` or `use 5.014000`

Comment: @Joel From this point of view you are correct - you have to define for yourself what perl versions you are (and will be) targetting. I am personally targetting `use 5.010` these days, mostly because of `given` and smartmatches. But provided you are making some general library, you may want more backward compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Good syntactic sugar is important.  Perl itself is "only" syntactic sugar over C which sugars assembler which sugars machine code.

This will not change how my top level usage per your example, but will help to reduce the awkward syntax found when using complex structures, ie "push @($this->{somekey}), $stuff" becomes "push $this->{somekey}, $stuff".

Comment: agreed, see my comment to Eric, Thanks